# ForeignKey is not working django, I am using custom user model and I try both MySQL and PostgreSQL

Tags: python, django

in my SubUser model ForeignKey is not working when I add some sub user it does not get main user id to its user_id field. I try all solutions from stack overflow and I try this in both MySQL and PostgreSQL, here my codes:

dashboard/model.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth.models import BaseUserManager
from account.models import Account
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

# Create your models here.


class CustomUserAdmin(BaseUserManager):
    ordering = ('email',)


class SubUser(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name="email", max_length=60, unique=True)
    fullname = models.CharField(max_length=220)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=220)
    user_role = models.CharField(max_length=220)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.fullname
```

dashboard/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from . import forms
from django.conf import settings


# Create your views here.
@login_required(login_url='account:index')
def dashboard(request):
    return render(request, 'dashboard/table.html')


@login_required(login_url='account:index')
def add_sub_user(request):
    form = forms.AddSubUserForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        obj = form.save(commit=False)
        obj.save()
        print(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request, 'dashboard/add_subuser.html',context)
```

account/modules.py

```
class Account(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name="email", max_length=220, unique=True)
    fullname = models.CharField(max_length=220)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=220, unique=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=220)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='data joined', auto_now_add=True)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='last login', auto_now_add=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=220, unique=True, blank=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['phone_number']

    objects = MyAccountManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.fullname

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return self.is_admin

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True
```

in settings.py , I did : AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'account.Account'

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I have found solution.
in dashboard/views.py I added

```
obj.user = request.user
```

now it is working